# View not showing up in both, simulator and device, in xcode 6

Tags: ios8, xcode6, ios7.1

I have a view that has a search display controller, a table view and a toolbar at the bottom. I upgraded to Xcode 6 and tried to run my app. The view simply doesn't show up in simulator or device.

The deployment target is ios 7.1. I understand the search display controller is deprecated from ios 8 but from other threads i came to know it should run fine if the deployment target is 7.1. Moreover, I am trying to run the app in the 7.1 simulator for iPhone 5 so that shouldn't be an issue at all.

All I get is a blank view with the navigation bar. I checked if the view was hidden and it wasn't. Nor are the search display controllers, the tool bar or the table view.

With breakpoints i checked if viewDidLoad: and viewDidAppear: are invoked and they are without errors. I haven't changed my code at all.

Can someone tell me what could be wrong? Autolayout is enabled and i have tried resetting to suggested constraints.

Comment: I re designed the whole view controller and its working now. seems to have been a bug in xcode 6

Answer (score 0):

I re designed the whole view controller and its working now. seems to have been a bug in xcode 6